# For Loop through cells in TableView Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am actually trying to approach a little app that sends mail with a holiday checklist (HolidayTVC).

For this I configured the following:

```
    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {


    var row = ""


    for cell in tableView.visibleCells() as! [HolidayTVCell] {

        var name = cell.labelName.text
        var toDo = cell.labelDetail2.text
        var plantimg = cell.imagePlant.image


        var newlineimg = "picture\n"
        var newlineplant = name! + "<br>" + toDo
        var row = (row + newlineimg + newlineplant) as String

    }

   var mail = row
   println(row)





    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self


    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["example@mail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Holiday Plan")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(mail, isHTML: true)

    return mailComposerVC
}
```

The output of the for-loop is nil. I could not print a line. Maybe my approach to this is very old-school as I was used to in other languages.

Thank you!
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad Losiowaty addressed your immediate question, but I would not advise iterating through the `visibleCells`. What if there were more items than were currently visible?

In generally, you should not be pulling data from UI controls, regardless. The app presumably has some model array that is used for populating the cells, so when sending this email, the app should go back to that model array and pull the data from there. Don't pull data from the cells.

Comment: thank you for your answer. you are right...there is a coredata entity behind it. but i use a function inside the TableView that doesn't store inside core-data.

Comment: Is there a Chance to do both or should i count coredata?

Comment: If you've loaded all of the core data into some in-memory collection, then you can use that collection. If not, go back to Core Data.

Comment: And the value (actually its only one) that is not there? Its a comment append to the tableview cell on Click. But how will my for function Look like? Can you please Show me an example?

Comment: The view controller's job is (a) to populate the cells with model data, (b) to capture user input and update the model; and (c) initiate tasks in response to the user's interactions. If the value is not in the model, then it would appear that the view controller is failing to perform step (b). That's a problem and you should fix that first. But never rely upon views (esp table cells) to hold the data: Always store the information in the model.

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = ""
for cell in tableView.visibleCells() as! [HolidayTVCell] {

    var name = cell.labelName.text
    var toDo = cell.labelDetail2.text
    var plantimg = cell.imagePlant.image


    var newlineimg = "picture\n"
    var newlineplant = name! + "<br>" + toDo
    var row = (row + newlineimg + newlineplant) as String // <<--- issue here!

}
var mail = row
println(row)
```

The issue is in the marked line. You are creating another `row` variable, and it hides the one declared outside the loop. Simply remove `var` in marked line and it should be fine.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. The little ones are sometimes the hardest to catch.